# Postfix replace string in Received: header

Tags: postfix

I am using Postfix, and trying to replace the string "14.03.0513.000" with "15.20.7091.31" in a "Received:" header similar to the one below:

`Received: from srv1.somedomain.com ([11.12.13.14]) by srv2 ([12.13.14.15]) with mapi id 14.03.0513.000; Fri, 15 Dec 2023 14:28:13 -0500`

However, I can't seem to get the syntax right. I tried something like this in /etc/postfix/header_checks, but as soon as I enable it, Postfix won't accept the inbound message (getting 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error)

`/^Received:(.*)14\.03\.0513\.000(.*)/ REPLACE Received:${1}15.20.7091.31${2}`

I can run

`postmap -q "Received: from srv1.somedomain.com ([11.12.13.14]) by srv2 ([12.13.14.15]) with mapi id 14.03.0513.000; Fri, 15 Dec 2023 14:28:13 -0500" regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks`

and I receive the reply

`REPLACE Received: from srv1.somedomain.com ([11.12.13.14]) by srv2 ([12.13.14.15]) with mapi id 15.20.7091.31; Fri, 15 Dec 2023 14:28:13 -0500`

which seems to be right, but postfix still rejects the message.
Any idea what I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version

```
/^Received: from (.*) by (.*) with mapi id 14\.03\.0513\.000;(.*)/ REPLACE Received: from ${1} by ${2} with mapi id 15.20.7091.31;${3}
```

This modification captures specific parts of the "Received:" header to ensure a more accurate replacement. After making this adjustment, reload or restart Postfix, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still no luck, Postfix rejects the message even though the string replacement verifies OK when I try it with postmap.